# node js mongodb get data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new in node js. I'm trying to get data from mongodb data, the data is stored perfectly. But when i want to get it back it's not working i'm using an array then i pass it to the html page, the elements of the array change only in loop for, after that i always get array.lengh equals to 1.

```
var express = require('express');
var async = require('express-async');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb');
var assert = require('assert');

var router = express.Router();


var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";



router.get('/',function (req,res,next) {
aray = [{
    FirstName: "da",
    LastName: "m",
    contry: "l"
}]
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

    if (err) throw err;
    var cursor = db.collection('usercollection').find();

    console.log("funBD")

    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log(doc);
        if (doc != null)
            aray.push(doc);
    },function () {
        db.close();
        res.render('Profil',{items:aray});

    });
    });

  });

module.exports = router;
```

the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    h1{
        tab-size: 20;
        text-align: center;
    }
  </style>

   </head>
<body>
<% for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) { %>
  <li>
    <%= items[i].FirstName %>
  </li>
    <% } %>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of MongoDb do you use? I check the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor) and I see that instead of cursor.each() you have to use cursor.forEach(). Is it working with this change?

Comment: i did try that but when i use cursor.forEach  i got this error              
 TypeError: cursor.Foreach is not a function

Comment: the version of MongoDb is 3.4

Comment: Did you try with the .hasNext() condition?

Comment: i just did a console log inside the loop , the loop works  the problem is the array lost the elements pushed in ones the loop end :/

Comment: So if you console log the array within the loop, you see it get filled, but at the end of the loop the array is empty?

Comment: Yes, exaclty also the second callback is never executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
db.collection('usercollection').find().toArray(function (err, docs) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log(docs);
    aray = aray.concat(docs);

    db.close();
    res.render('Profil',{items:aray});
});
```